# The path (ImageSource) in WinRT to display an image that is saved in Pictures folder (not in app packages)

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

So, i've saved my image in

```
StorageFile picture = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

and  i want to display it in XAML :

```
 <Image  Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="0"
                x:Name="Photo"
                Source="ms-appx:///Pictures/test.png"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Stretch="Fill"
                Width="1024"
                Height="768">
        </Image>
```

and it's not working :(

Thank you very much for you help :)

Comment: I don't know that you need the ms-appx: part if it's just thrown in a folder, but you might also check what you have the build action set to on the properties of that image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't any [uri schemes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj655406.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) that work with a pictures library.

You wouldn't typically hard-code a URI to a pictures library file in your XAML anyway since you can't rely on that file being there.

If you store a list of files by paths somewhere you'd still have to load them using some code - perhaps using future access list, opening streams to the files etc.

You could probably create an `IValueConverter` or an attached behavior/`DependencyProperty` to convert a string to an `ImageSource`, but you could just as well do that in your view model.

Comment: Thank you. I am writing a Converter, indeed. :)